# Why does this MERGE statement cause the session to be killed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, merge, sql-server-2016

I have the below `MERGE` statement which is issued against the database:

```
MERGE "MySchema"."Point" AS t
USING (
       SELECT "ObjectId", "PointName", z."Id" AS "LocationId", i."Id" AS "Region"
         FROM @p1 AS d
         JOIN "MySchema"."Region" AS i ON i."Name" = d."Region"
    LEFT JOIN "MySchema"."Location" AS z ON z."Name" = d."Location" AND z."Region" = i."Id"
       ) AS s
   ON s."ObjectId" = t."ObjectId"
 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT ("ObjectId", "Name", "LocationId", "Region") VALUES (s."ObjectId", s."PointName", s."LocationId", s."Region")
 WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE 
     SET "Name" = s."PointName"
       , "LocationId" = s."LocationId"
       , "Region" = s."Region"
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
```

However, this causes the session to be terminated with the following error:

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 67 A severe error occurred on the
>   current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
>
> Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 67 A severe error occurred on the current
>   command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

I have put a short test script together which produces the error:

```
USE master;
GO
IF DB_ID('TEST') IS NOT NULL
DROP DATABASE "TEST";
GO
CREATE DATABASE "TEST";
GO
USE "TEST";
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF SCHEMA_ID('MySchema') IS NULL
EXECUTE('CREATE SCHEMA "MySchema"');
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('MySchema.Region', 'U') IS NULL
CREATE TABLE "MySchema"."Region" (
"Id" TINYINT IDENTITY NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_MySchema_Region" PRIMARY KEY,
"Name" VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "UK_MySchema_Region" UNIQUE
);
GO

INSERT [MySchema].[Region] ([Name]) 
VALUES (N'A'), (N'B'), (N'C'), (N'D'), (N'E'), ( N'F'), (N'G');

IF OBJECT_ID('MySchema.Location', 'U') IS NULL
CREATE TABLE "MySchema"."Location" (
"Id" SMALLINT IDENTITY NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_MySchema_Location" PRIMARY KEY,
"Region" TINYINT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "FK_MySchema_Location_Region" FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES "MySchema"."Region" ("Id"),
"Name" VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "UK_MySchema_Location" UNIQUE ("Region", "Name") 
);
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('MySchema.Point', 'U') IS NULL
CREATE TABLE "MySchema"."Point" (
"ObjectId" BIGINT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_MySchema_Point" PRIMARY KEY,
"Name" VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
"LocationId" SMALLINT NULL CONSTRAINT "FK_MySchema_Point_Location" FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES "MySchema"."Location"("Id"),
"Region" TINYINT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "FK_MySchema_Point_Region" FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES "MySchema"."Region" ("Id"),
CONSTRAINT "UK_MySchema_Point" UNIQUE ("Name", "Region", "LocationId")
);
GO

-- CONTAINS HISTORIC Point DATA
IF OBJECT_ID('MySchema.PointHistory', 'U') IS NULL
CREATE TABLE "MySchema"."PointHistory" (
"Id" BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_MySchema_PointHistory" PRIMARY KEY,
"ObjectId" BIGINT NOT NULL,
"Name" VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
"LocationId" SMALLINT NULL,
"Region" TINYINT NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE TYPE "MySchema"."PointTable" AS TABLE (
"ObjectId"      BIGINT          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"PointName"     VARCHAR(64)     NOT NULL,
"Location"      VARCHAR(16)     NULL,
"Region"        VARCHAR(8)      NOT NULL,
UNIQUE ("PointName", "Region", "Location")
);
GO

DECLARE @p1 "MySchema"."PointTable";

insert into @p1 values(10001769996,N'ABCDEFGH',N'N/A',N'E')

MERGE "MySchema"."Point" AS t
USING (
       SELECT "ObjectId", "PointName", z."Id" AS "LocationId", i."Id" AS "Region"
         FROM @p1 AS d
         JOIN "MySchema"."Region" AS i ON i."Name" = d."Region"
    LEFT JOIN "MySchema"."Location" AS z ON z."Name" = d."Location" AND z."Region" = i."Id"
       ) AS s
   ON s."ObjectId" = t."ObjectId"
 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT ("ObjectId", "Name", "LocationId", "Region") VALUES (s."ObjectId", s."PointName", s."LocationId", s."Region")
 WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE 
     SET "Name" = s."PointName"
       , "LocationId" = s."LocationId"
       , "Region" = s."Region"
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
```

If I remove the `OUTPUT` clause then the error does not occur. Also, if I remove the `deleted` reference then the error does not occur. So I looked at the MSDN documents for the `OUTPUT` clause which state:

> DELETED cannot be used with the OUTPUT clause in the INSERT statement.

Which makes sense to me, however the entire point of `MERGE` is that you may not know in advance.

Additionally, the below script works perfectly fine regardless of the action that is taken:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Target(EmployeeID int, EmployeeName varchar(10), 
     CONSTRAINT Target_PK PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeID));
CREATE TABLE dbo.Source(EmployeeID int, EmployeeName varchar(10), 
     CONSTRAINT Source_PK PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeID));
GO
INSERT dbo.Target(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES(100, 'Mary');
INSERT dbo.Target(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES(101, 'Sara');
INSERT dbo.Target(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES(102, 'Stefano');

GO
INSERT dbo.Source(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) Values(103, 'Bob');
INSERT dbo.Source(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) Values(104, 'Steve');
GO
-- MERGE statement with the join conditions specified correctly.
USE tempdb;
GO
BEGIN TRAN;
MERGE Target AS T
USING Source AS S
ON (T.EmployeeID = S.EmployeeID) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND S.EmployeeName LIKE 'S%' 
    THEN INSERT(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES(S.EmployeeID, S.EmployeeName)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET T.EmployeeName = S.EmployeeName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND T.EmployeeName LIKE 'S%'
    THEN DELETE 
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
ROLLBACK TRAN;
GO
```

Also, I have other queries that use the `OUTPUT` in the same fashion as the one that is throwing an error and they work perfectly fine - the only difference between them is the tables that take part in the `MERGE`.

This is causing major problems in production for us. I have reproduced this error in SQL2014 and SQL2016 on both VM and Physical with 128GB RAM, 12 x 2.2GHZ Cores, Windows Server 2012 R2.

The estimated execution plan generated from the query can be found here:

[Estimated Execution Plan](http://pastebin.com/mvQs2fYm)

Comment: Can the query generate an estimated plan? (Also, this won't shock a lot of people, but [I recommend the old upsert methodology anyway](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) - your `MERGE` doesn't have `HOLDLOCK`, for one, so it isn't immune from race conditions, and there are still other bugs to consider even after you resolve - or report - whatever is causing this issue.)

Comment: It gives a stack dump with an access violation. As far as I can see when unwinding the stack here http://i.stack.imgur.com/f9aWa.png You should raise this with Microsoft PSS if this is causing major problems for you. Specifically it seems to be `deleted.ObjectId` that is causing the problem. `OUTPUT $action, inserted.*,  deleted.Name, deleted.LocationId, deleted.Region` works fine.

Comment: Concur with Martin. In the meantime, see if you can avoid the issue by not using the `MySchema.PointTable` type, and just using a naked `VALUES()` clause, or #temp table, or table variable, inside the `USING`. Might help isolate contributing factors.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I tried using a temp table and the same error occurred. I will raise it with product support - in the meantime I rewrote the query to not use merge so that we could keep prod running.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a bug.

It is related to `MERGE`-specific hole-filling optimizations used to avoid explicit Halloween Protection and to eliminate a join, and how these interact with other update plan features.

There are details about those optimizations in my article, [The Halloween Problem – Part 3](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/02/sql-plan/halloween-problem-part-3).

The giveaway is the Insert followed by a Merge *on the same table*:

[image: Plan fragment]

#### Workarounds

There are several ways to defeat this optimization, and so avoid the bug.

1. Use an undocumented trace flag to force explicit Halloween Protection:

   ```
   OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8692);
   ```
2. Change the `ON` clause to:

   ```
   ON s."ObjectId" = t."ObjectId" + 0
   ```
3. Change the table type `PointTable` to replace the primary key with:

   ```
   ObjectID bigint NULL UNIQUE CLUSTERED CHECK (ObjectId IS NOT NULL)
   ```

   The `CHECK` constraint part is optional, included to preserve the original null-rejecting property of a primary key.

'Simple' update query processing (foreign key checks, unique index maintenance, and output columns) is complex enough to begin with. Using `MERGE` adds several additional layers to that. Combine that with the specific optimization mentioned above, and you have a great way to encounter edge-case bugs like this.

One more to add to the [long line of bugs](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) that have been reported with `MERGE`.